Problem with TextField in Jetpack Compose
I am trying to create a simple TextField in Jetpack Compose with a leading icon and a placeholder string Search....
But when I give the TextField a custom height of 48.dp, the placeholder text gets slightly cut-off from the bottom:

Here's my code:
TextField(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(48.dp),
        value = value,
        onValueChange = { value = it },
        placeholder = {
            Text(
                text = "Search...",
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                fontSize = 12.sp,
            )
        },
        shape = CircleShape,
        leadingIcon = {
            Icon(
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.search_24px),
                contentDescription = "Search"
            )
        },
        colors = TextFieldDefaults.colors(
            unfocusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
            focusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent
        )
    )

I want the text to be of a comparable size to the container (and fully visible of course) while keeping the container height at 48.dp:

Please help!

Well, there is not enough space anymore for the text with size 12.sp and the inner padding of the TextField. Can you describe what you expected to happen instead?

@Leviathan It seems the text remains part-hidden even when I decrease the font size.

At all, providing the size of the components is not recommended. instead, you have an image or something visually. it would help if you worked with font size or standard sizes.

The placeholder cutoff is because of the TextField minimum height. The minimum height of TextField is 56.dp.
You can use label = { Text(text = "Search...")} instead of placeholder.
If you don't want to use the label, remove .height() or change .height(56.dp). Then you get what you want.
